# How can I add a link/href/hyperlink in JSON script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to create a dynamic array/script and I need to add some link in my JSON return so that, I can create a long array which inculude dynamic list or sources with a prepared JSON file.

[image: My HTML's picture]

```html
<table id="userdata" border="5">            
        <th>Revision  Date</th>
        <th>Document  Name</th>
        <th>Department </th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Link</th>     
</table>
```

```js
var data = {

    "person": [{
        "revisiondate": "21 April 2016",
        "documentname": "1658MC",
        "department": "Sales",
        "description": "Available",
        "link": "href=1658MC.pdf"
    }, {
        "revisiondate": "16 April 2016",
        "documentname": "VCX16B",
        "department": "Enginnering",
        "description": "Not Available",
        "link": "href=VCX16B.pdf"
    }, {
        "revisiondate": "15 March 2016",
        "documentname": "AB36F",
        "department": "Custumer Services",
        "description":  "Not Available",
        "link": "href=AB36F.pdf"
    }, {
        "revisiondate": "12 Agust 2016",
        "documentname": "FC25D",
        "department": "Technical Support",
        "description": "Not Available",
        "link": "href=FC25D.pdf"
    }]
} 
//$.getJSON("new4.json", function(data) {
// console.log(data);

//$.getJSON('new4.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
        var tblRow =    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate + 
                        "</td><td>" + person.documentname + 
                        "</td><td>" + person.department +
                        "</td><td>" + person.description + 
                        "</td><td>" + person.link +
                        "</td></tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });
```

[image: Clicking on marking area]

How can I add a link to my script line such as when I click to this link this opened to my source like a PDF or HTML. I could do that in HTML but when I try to do with JSON I could not.

```
"</td><td><a  target='_blank' href='\\mustafa02\group\Manuals\Reviewed\ "+ person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"' >"+person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"</a></td>"
```

my pdfs is in the Reviewed Folder. So my folder path is shown above. `\\mustafa02\group\Manuals\Reviewed\`

Comment: You already know how to create HTML elements from JS: you're creating a bunch of TD elements. It's not too big a leap to get from there to creating an anchor element. It would be easier if the data just said `"link": "FC25D.pdf"`.

Comment: Edit `"</td><td>"+person.link+"</td></tr>"` to ``"</td><td><a "+person.link+">PDF</a></td></tr>"``

Comment: You forgot the HREF @NewToJS

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder the href is already within `person.link` ;) => **"link": "href=FC25D.pdf"**

Comment: Your right. I did not see that. Why would he want that in his json data

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder I don't know, it would be better to leave it out but since it's in there  :p If that fails then I guess it just means removing it. `.replace("href","");`

Comment: @NewToJS your method do not working too :/

Comment: Seems like over kill. He could just add single quotes to the data like so "link": "href='AB36F.pdf'" and use "<a " + person.link + ">link text</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<a>` tag with `href` and `target="_black"` for opening the link in new tab and use split to remove the href from json.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
    <table id="userdata" border="5">            
            <th>Revision  Date</th>
            <th>Document  Name</th>
            <th>Department </th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Link</th>     
    </table>
<script>
        var data = {
        "person": [{
            "revisiondate": "21 April 2016",
            "documentname": "1658MC",
            "department": "Sales",
            "description": "Available",
            "link": "href=1658MC.pdf"
        }, {
            "revisiondate": "16 April 2016",
            "documentname": "VCX16B",
            "department": "Enginnering",
            "description": "Not Available",
            "link": "href=VCX16B.pdf"
        }, {
            "revisiondate": "15 March 2016",
            "documentname": "AB36F",
            "department": "Custumer Services",
            "description":  "Not Available",
            "link": "href=AB36F.pdf"
        }, {
            "revisiondate": "12 Agust 2016",
            "documentname": "FC25D",
            "department": "Technical Support",
            "description": "Not Available",
            "link": "href=FC25D.pdf"
        }]
    } 
    //$.getJSON("new4.json", function(data) {
    // console.log(data);

    //$.getJSON('new4.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
            var tblRow =    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate + 
                            "</td><td>" + person.documentname + 
                            "</td><td>" + person.department +
                            "</td><td>" + person.description + 
                            "</td><td><a target='_blank' href='"+ person.link.split('href=')[1]+"' >"+person.link.split('href=')[1]+"</a></td></tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
        //});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once again, this won't work.... the anchor href will look like href=href=something and you need to backslash those double quotes within the string otherwise you will have a syntax error.

Comment: Json split is over kill. Just remove the href from the JSON data

Comment: So, I have a another question. How can change this code as open external file with href. I mean this method working but just can open document which in same file. And I have another file which I need to open some document in there. Finally, if my path like Z:\path\to\my\file, how can I integrate this code as newest version? @Bhuwan

Comment: use target="_blank"

Comment: I am already using target="_blank". But I wanna create a path to get some document according to my json. For example,last one FC25D.pdf in same folder with html. And works good. I want to add new document as .pdf which have path like C:\desktop\folder\example.pdf. How can I create a path and integrate to this code? thank you for your interest by the way @Bhuwan

Comment: @Bhuwan can we do that, I couln't find syntax about this split code!

Comment: just add the path to href=path/asddsa.pdf

Comment: @Bhuwan can you see the my edit.

 I want to get pdfs from this folder, so how can I integrate this path to your code. Really I tried a lof of time to fix it, but I couldn't. I am really sorry to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
            var tblRow =    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate + 
                            "</td><td>" + person.documentname + 
                            "</td><td>" + person.department +
                            "</td><td>" + person.description + 
                            "</td><a href='" + person.link + "'>link text</a><td>" +
                            "</td></tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
```

You should remove the attrribute 'href' from your json

Or you could just add single quotes to your json data links like so

```
var data = {
        "person": [{
            "revisiondate": "21 April 2016",
            "documentname": "1658MC",
            "department": "Sales",
            "description": "Available",
            "link": "href='1658MC.pdf'"
        }, {
            "revisiondate": "16 April 2016",
            "documentname": "VCX16B",
            "department": "Enginnering",
            "description": "Not Available",
            "link": "href='VCX16B.pdf'"
        }, {
            "revisiondate": "15 March 2016",
            "documentname": "AB36F",
            "department": "Custumer Services",
            "description":  "Not Available",
            "link": "href='AB36F.pdf'"
        }, {
            "revisiondate": "12 Agust 2016",
            "documentname": "FC25D",
            "department": "Technical Support",
            "description": "Not Available",
            "link": "href='FC25D.pdf'"
        }]


$.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
            var tblRow =    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate + 
                            "</td><td>" + person.documentname + 
                            "</td><td>" + person.department +
                            "</td><td>" + person.description + 
                            "</td><a " + person.link + ">link text</a><td>" +
                            "</td></tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
```

Comment: This won't work. The anchor will look like this **<a href=href=FC25D.pdf>link text</a>** Maybe try `"</td><td><a "+person.link+">PDF</a></td></tr>"`

Comment: Updated Answer.